# How to combine dialog prompt observables in a way that stops on the first deny

Tags: rxjs

This is such a trivial thing to do with synchronous calls that it's driving me nuts how hard it seems to be to do. It also seems strange that a modal dialog returns an observable, but that's existing code and I need to understand why it should change before I change it and refactor other code.

Both of the approaches work but feel ugly and overblown to me, so I'm really hoping there's a better way to do this.

My instinctive approach:

```
keepGoing = true;

if (PromptCondition1True) { keepGoing = confirm("question 1") }

if (keepGoing && PromptCondition2True) { keepGoing = confirm("question 2") }

if (keepGoing) {
  this.doProcessing.process(processingRequest).subscribe();
}
```

Approach 1:

```
    iif(() => this.isDirty,
      defer(() => this.openConfirmDialog("Pending Updates", "There are changes that will be ignored for processing, do you want to process anyway? Cancel and press update to clear this warning")),
      of(true))
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result === true) {
          return iif(() => this.selection.selected.some(x => !x.asdf.isActive),
            defer(() => this.openConfirmDialog("Inactive asdf", "Inactive asdf are selected for processing, do you want to continue?")),
            of(true))
            .subscribe(result => {
              if (result === true) {
                return this.doProcessing.process(processingRequest).subscribe();
              }
            });
        }
      });
```

Approach 2

```
    of(true).pipe(
      switchMap(() => iif(() => this.isDirty,
        defer(() => this.openConfirmDialog("Pending Updates", "There are changes that will be ignored for processing, do you want to process anyway? Cancel and press update to clear this warning")),
        of(true))),

      first(),
      filter(x => x === true),
      switchMap(() => iif(() => this.selection.selected.some(x => !x.asdf.isActive),
        defer(() => this.openConfirmDialog("Inactive asdf", "Inactive asdf are selected for processing, do you want to continue?")),
        of(true))),
      first(),
      filter(x => x === true),
      switchMap(() => this.doProcessing.process(processingRequest))).subscribe();
```

Comment: The reason you'd return an observable for a modal is to not block the main thread. There might be some other code that needs to be executed in the background. This is especially true if you're using Angular.

Comment: Usually it's not recommended to do nested subscriptions, so I'd rather go with the second approach. Do you need the alert and the `first()`?

Comment: I don't need the alert and will edit that out, missed debug code. I'm not sure about the first. I'm only expecting a single boolean result from the dialog and I still don't fully understand mixing pipes with observables.